# How can I reset recent documents on every login?

Tags: privacy

I want to create a script that allow the recent document to be reset every time i log.

I have 10 public computer (internet café) using ubuntu.

now, i have 10+ documents in my recent documents on each (which are the users) and I want to erase these to make sure the next customer does not open it.

My idea is to copy a file (from a usb or network or something) and overwrite the file everytime someone log off

Is there a better way? If not how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might like [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/), with a version for Ubuntu 8.04 - 11.10.

> BleachBit quickly frees disk space and tirelessly guards your privacy. Free cache, delete cookies, clear Internet history, shred temporary files, delete logs, and discard junk you didn't know was there. Designed for Linux and Windows systems, it wipes clean 90 applications including Firefox, Internet Explorer, Adobe Flash, Google Chrome, Opera, Safari,and more. Beyond simply deleting files, BleachBit includes advanced features such as shredding files to prevent recovery, wiping free disk space to hide traces of files deleted by other applications, and vacuuming Firefox to make it faster. Better than free, BleachBit is open source.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run ubuntu in kiosk mode, or install a kiosk specific distro.

http://jacob.steelsmith.org/category/section/ubuntu-kiosk-edition

http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/

http://webconverger.com/

http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kiosk/